# Issue using Git with Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio-2008, version-control, github

I am **almost** convineced to use Git with visual studio for source control. I have read several posts, about the features it provides.

I have a development team of about 5 developers(we work remotely), but the issue is I don't have a server which can be online 24*7. I assume, I can make my PC a git server, but again there would be issues in case of system crashes or power failure or other network issues.
My question is : **Do I have any option with git, that my project source code remains on GitHub webserver(which would have a uptime of about 99.9%), and every developer connects to the GitHub webserver.**

Comment: erm. Looking for git push/git pull? You may want to read up on DVCS in general

Comment: this is exactly how git would work...

Comment: If I use a free account/public repository, can anyone change source code without my permission?

Comment: Yes, you do have that option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper answer is "just use *github*".

However, *for you specifically* I do not recommend Git; this is because it is evident that you don't read manuals and documentation, which is a **must** for Git users.

Comment: @vaibhav - **read my text fully!**, think about it. Due to exactly this reason not recommended

Comment: @LazyBadger Spot on! `+1` :)

Answer (score 0):

Ya, You have GITServer like CodePlex where you can create your project repositories.. Which will be 24x7